# Magento 2 Caching data from the database

Tags: magento2, database, cache

I'm currently looking at caching parts of the database. For example, I have a JSON string in a column called object_data. Now I don't want to connect to the database every time I fetch that data, instead, I would like to cache it.

I didn't really find anything related to this question on the web so I don't know if this is even an option or if it's a good practice. Could anyone tell me if this is possible and hook me up with an example.

Thanks in advance!